# How to fix the white spaces in sections on background color CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have my page broken up into "sections" but cannot get rid of this white space above and below each section. Any tips would be great!!

[image: Imgur]

The bright yellow color is just to show that it happens on the next section below.

I've tried removing the padding and margin on all sections, as well as the body but that little strip of white spacing is still there. I also tried changing the sections to divs as well as putting my img into an a href or another div. Not sure why I'm getting this!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Fun Project | Kay Larson</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header__left-side">
      <img class="logo-placeholder" src="logo-placeholder.jpeg">
      <span class="header__titles">
        <h1>KAYLA LARSON</h1>
        <h2>web designer</h2>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="header__right-side">
    </div>
    <div class="header__social-icons">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/kayla.larson.710">
        <img src="icons/facebook-logo-button.svg" class="img__fb">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/kaylalarson4/">
        <img src="icons/linkedin-button.svg" class="img__linkedin">
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/Kay60372608">
        <img src="icons/twitter.svg" class="img__twitter">
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="images/Kayla Larson - F.jpg" class="img__self">
  </a>
  <section class="section__top-get-started">
    <h2 class="h__get-started">Creating Things. <br> Happy Mind.</h2>
    <h3 class="h3__get-started">The ways creating can improve your life.</h3>
    <button class="btn__get-started">Let's Start</button>
  </section>
  <section class="section__about-me">
    <h2>Who I Am</h2>
    <h3>I'm Kay, a Web Developer.</h3>
    <p class="section__body-para">I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and edit me. It’s easy. Just click “Edit Text” or double click me to add your own content and make changes to the font. Feel free to drag and drop me anywhere you like on your page. I’m a great place for you to tell a story and let your users know a little more about you.

    This is a great space to write long text about your company and your services. You can use this space to go into a little more detail about your company. Talk about your team and what services you provide. Tell your visitors the story of how you came up with the idea for your business and what makes you different from your competitors. Make your company stand out and show your visitors who you are.</p>
    <button class="btn__contact-me">Contact Me</button>
  </section>
  <section class="section__more-info">
    <h2>For More Information</h2>
    <form class="form__subscribe">
      <h4>Subscribe</h4>
      <input type="test" name="Subscribe" placeholder="Enter your email here">
      <button class="btn__submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </section>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header__left-side {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-placeholder {
  height: 75px;
  margin: 30px 10px 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

.header__titles {
  margin: 30px 0px 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.img__fb,
.img__linkedin,
.img__twitter {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
}

.img__self {
    width: 100%;
 }

 .section__top-get-started {
  background-color: #fdf9ba;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .h__get-started {
  position: relative;
  margin: 45px 0px 5px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 280px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center !important;
 }

 .h3__get-started {
  width: 280px;
  font-family: "Garamond", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0px 18px;
  left: 20px;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .btn__get-started {
  height: 45px;
  min-height: 19px;
  width: 104px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0px 36px 0;
  left: 108px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: grey;
 }
```

Comment: add `margin-top: -3px;` to `.section__top-get-started` even at the bottom

Comment: that worked!!! thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if those borders are from the image itself

```
<img src="images/Kayla Larson - F.jpg" class="img__self">
```

If you could provide the image it would be easier to see.

Comment: @KaylaLarson i think he meant to say if the image itself has white borders on top and bottom

Answer (score 1):

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

Generally appears because of Descenders but i couldn't see why would this happen to you. Try the css property above, It solved my issue in many projects

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two things need an update. First, the image display needs to be block and the other sections display also needs to be flex. Please try this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header__left-side {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-placeholder {
  height: 75px;
  margin: 30px 10px 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

.header__titles {
  margin: 30px 0px 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Playfair Display", serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: lighter;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.img__fb,
.img__linkedin,
.img__twitter {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px;
}

.img__self {
display:block;
    width: 100%;
 }

 .section__top-get-started {
  background-color: #fdf9ba;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }
 .section__about-me,.section__more-info{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .h__get-started {
  position: relative;
  margin: 45px 0px 5px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 280px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center !important;
 }

 .h3__get-started {
  width: 280px;
  font-family: "Garamond", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0px 18px;
  left: 20px;
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
 }

 .btn__get-started {
  height: 45px;
  min-height: 19px;
  width: 104px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0px 36px 0;
  left: 108px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: grey;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in "h2 { margin-top: 2px; }", remove it and set padding-top for ".section__about-me". Title moves the whole block, therefore, move the title with internal padding instead. This will solve an issue in one place, but you understand logic.